# Experimenting with Tincan/XAPI project created using Adobe Presenter

Tags: adobe, scorm

Using Adobe Presenter, I have created a presentation with an opening slide, two quiz questions, and a concluding slide.  I have published as a Tincan presentation (have confirmed that there is a tincan.xml file published), uploaded to the web and run the presentation. The presentation runs fine, quiz works fine.  Two problems:

1)
The index.htm file references

```
./data/resources/ha/wr_/OpenAjaxManagedHub-all.js
```

But there is no such directory as wr_
so naturally no files in it.

Chrome dev tools console reports the file not found.

2)
tc-config.js contains the following reference to a publicly available Record Store, so I would expect an attempt to store the activity there when the presentation concludes:

```
TC_RECORD_STORES = [
    {
        endpoint: "https://cloud.scorm.com/ScormEngineInterface/TCAPI/public/",
        auth:     "Basic VGVzdFVzZXI6cGFzc3dvcmQ="
    }
];
```

But looking in Chrome dev tools Network tab, there is no XMLHttpRequest.  In fact, the only thing in the Network tab is a bunch of GETs for the files in the presentation.

Also, my understanding is that if it had been stored, it would show up here:

```
http://tincanapi.com/report-sample/
```

And it does not show up there.

Don't know if these two problems are related.

Any clues will be appreciated.

Comment: Right; that's pretty conclusive your package is not sending data. Please can you share a copy of your package and a screenshot of your publish settings in Captivate? I do not believe the missing OpenAjaxManagedHub-all.js is related, but could be wrong. Have you tried removing that line from index.html and seeing if you get any different errors?

Comment: Hi Andrew - I published with Presenter, not Captivate. Not sure which screen you would want from that, but I put a link to all the files below. I tried commenting out that line; that eliminates the "file not found" but doesn't cause any data to be sent to the LRS.  You can run the presentation here: http://greendept.com/presenter3/index.htm  Also all files archived here: http://greendept.com/presenter3/presenter3_hurwicz.zip   Thanks in advanced for any tips you can provide!

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the package; it just doesn't seem to be trying to send any data. Do Adobe provide any instructions for how to configure Presenter publish settings?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I'll look into this further.